# YouTube.Search.List search returns nothing

Tags: java, android, arraylist, youtube-data-api

I am developing an app that implements a SearchView used to get YouTube video results by keywords. The results are then refined by thumbnail url, video title, channel name, and video views, whose values are stored in an ArrayList. The ArrayList then sends values to a java class that then puts these results in a ListView to generate "results" for the user much like how the YouTube app returns videos. I am using the YouTube Data API V3 and am using slightly modified code from the Google example code. Here is my searchview listener code.

*searchedList is the ArrayList that I would like to send the string values to.*

```
                            searchYouTube = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.videoSearch);
                            searchYouTube.setQueryHint("Search for a YouTube video");
                            searchYouTube.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                                    String query = searchYouTube.getQuery().toString();
                                    searchedList.clear();


                                    try {
                                        new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                                            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                                            }
                                        }).setApplicationName("myApp").build();

                                        // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
                                        YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

                                        // Set your developer key from the Google Cloud Console for
                                        // non-authenticated requests. See:
                                        // https://cloud.google.com/console
                                        search.setKey(apiKey);
                                        search.setQ(query);

                                        // Restrict the search results to only include videos. See:
                                        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type
                                        search.setType("video");

                                        // To increase efficiency, only retrieve the fields that the
                                        // application uses.
                                        search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/channelTitle,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");

                                        search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

                                        SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
                                        List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
                                        if (searchResultList != null) {
                                            apppendToSearchArray(searchResultList.iterator(), query);
                                        }

                                    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                                        System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                                                + e.getDetails().getMessage());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
                                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                                        t.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                                    return false;
                                }


                            });
```

Here is my method 'appendToSearchArray' method that is called in the above code to actually put the wanted values in order into the ArrayList.

```
private static void apppendToSearchArray(Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults, String query) {


    if (!iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(" There aren't any results for your query.");
    }

    while (iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {

        SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
        ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();


        // Confirm that the result represents a video. Otherwise, the
        // item will not contain a video ID.
        if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {
            Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();


            VideoDetails singleVidDetails = new VideoDetails(thumbnail.getUrl().toString(),singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle().toString(),singleVideo.getSnippet().getChannelTitle().toString(),"0");
            searchedList.add(singleVidDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

"VideoDetails" is a java class I created that actually acts as a medium to retrieve String values of thumbnail, title, channel, and views and sends these Strings to an adapter class that actually implements them into my ListView. However, when the application is run and I submit a query via the SearchView the listview does not show any new results. Here is my logcat.

[Logcat.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huv9I.png)

ANY help is greatly appreciated because I am very confused.

Comment: Just for sure, after submit query is not searchResultList null right?